# Change element tag name Mootools

Tags: mootools

I am at the end , sooo many posts and Fiddle examples on how to change tag name of all elements on page with Jquery but NONE with mootools. Is there any way to do it? I need to convert all tr to div, not able to change the actual page html, must do it with Moo. Please help.

i have 15 tr's in a div , crazy huh!

```
<div id="mydiv">
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
...
</div>
```

I need to convert them to divs but keep all attributes and html within tr's in tact. PLEASE help! Thank you!

Comment: does it have TDs inside the TR and what do they change to?

Comment: no they are only tr's, what I did is picked them all and placed in the div with el.adopt  so I could toggle. they are all tr's with input and select fields

Comment: it works perfectt but IE7( as always ) does not allow tr's within that div without table and tbody , I tried that also but everything becomes a mess , so the best solution would be to change them to divs if IE7, right now im testing Jquery , this here , http://jsfiddle.net/WVb2Q/1/   I dont like this but is better than nothing

Comment: wait wait , sorry , yes td's are inside of them , it gos like this. <tr><td1><td2><input><tr><td1><td2>

Comment: replacing tags is piss easy but the problem you have is something else. doing a `<tr>` that's NOT a child of a `table` seems to (at least in firefox) result in HTML that STRIPS the TRs and leaves just the text nodes, getting rid of the invalid HTML. Hence you cannot target `#mydiv tr` via the selector engine...

Comment: Thnx for trying , I decided , and should have done earlier is to pick the actual inputs only and move them , bit more work on restyling but is more precise and cleaner , the empty tr/td's will be displayed none or trashed.  But for what is worth and the actual question , HOW in world do you change tag names , let say from p element to div ? I know I will need it sooner or later :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/4WatG/ - here is the output in FF 7: `foob bar <input>`. To answer your question on how, here's an example replacing an element with a div instead of the span. note that this recreates the element and the child elements so any events will be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing elements in mootools is easy, as long as the markup is not invalid as above.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/4WatG/1/

```
document.getElements("#mydiv span").each(function(el) {
     new Element("div", {
        html: el.get("html")
    }).replaces(el);
});
```

this will replace all spans for divs in the above markup (use spans instead of trs).

as stated up, http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/4WatG/ -> firefox strips invalid markup of TR not being a child of a table which makes it hard to target.

Comment: Thank you!  Goes in to snippets :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to leave this floating here.

```
Element.implement({'swapTagName': function(newTagName) {
    return new Element(newTagName, {html: this.get('html')}).replaces(this);
}});
```

Usage:

```
//cleaning HTML3.2 like it's 2012
target.getElements('font[size=5pt],b').swapTagName('h2').addClass('header_paragraphs');
target.getElements('font').swapTagName('p');
```